# How to do find and navigate in webstorm?

Tags: webstorm

What is the shortcut key for find and navigate in Webstorm IDE? I found it getting used in this video (http://youtu.be/IfUyUeYHffk?t=51s).
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a custom plugin: **AceJump**

http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin?pr=webide&pluginId=7086

Install from **Settings | Plugins**

Answer (score 1):

There is another implementation:

http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea_ce&pluginId=7163

[image: jump to char]
[image: jump and cut]